# Url change and display the keyword used in a serach component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a search bar that when you click on it, using redux bring the results and display a list of product. But the url stay the same how can I make the url show the keyword I use to search like this:

http://localhost/seach?q=keyword

Comment: You should use react-router to control the router of the application， and use react-router-redux to connect the route to the redux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this is the best way. But I'm using `history.pushState()` to change the url without reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router to control the router of the application， and use react-router-redux to connect the route to the redux.

```

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

// Apply the middleware to the store
const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

// Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
store.dispatch(push({
  pathname: 'search',
  query: {
    q: keyword
}))
```

```